# Hosting Django in Apache

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I try to host Django at Apache using mod_wsgi and following a nice tutorial. I have a Windows 7 OP, and I had everything set as described by the tutorial, however, I get this Error 500 for which I paste the ErrorLogs below:

```
[Mon Apr 06 14:37:28.669698 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7784:tid 1048] [client 95.47.51.217:48374] mod_wsgi (pid=7784): Failed to exec Python script file 'D:/Backup/Learning Python/Organized and important file/Learning files and sheets/Django_ Learning_ 1/weblog_app/weblog_app/wsgi.py'.
[Mon Apr 06 14:37:28.669698 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7784:tid 1048] [client 95.47.51.217:48374] mod_wsgi (pid=7784): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'D:/Backup/Learning Python/Organized and important file/Learning files and sheets/Django_ Learning_ 1/weblog_app/weblog_app/wsgi.py'.
[Mon Apr 06 14:37:28.669698 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7784:tid 1048] [client 95.47.51.217:48374] Traceback (most recent call last):\r
[Mon Apr 06 14:37:28.669698 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7784:tid 1048] [client 95.47.51.217:48374]   File "D:/Backup/Learning Python/Organized and important file/Learning files and sheets/Django_ Learning_ 1/weblog_app/weblog_app/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>\r
[Mon Apr 06 14:37:28.669698 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7784:tid 1048] [client 95.47.51.217:48374]     application = get_wsgi_application()\r
[Mon Apr 06 14:37:28.669698 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7784:tid 1048] [client 95.47.51.217:48374]   File "c:\\users\\adwy\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application\r
[Mon Apr 06 14:37:28.669698 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7784:tid 1048] [client 95.47.51.217:48374]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)\r
[Mon Apr 06 14:37:28.669698 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7784:tid 1048] [client 95.47.51.217:48374]   File "c:\\users\\adwy\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\__init__.py", line 19, in setup\r
[Mon Apr 06 14:37:28.669698 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7784:tid 1048] [client 95.47.51.217:48374]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)\r
[Mon Apr 06 14:37:28.669698 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7784:tid 1048] [client 95.47.51.217:48374]   File "c:\\users\\adwy\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\conf\\__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__\r
[Mon Apr 06 14:37:28.669698 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7784:tid 1048] [client 95.47.51.217:48374]     self._setup(name)\r
[Mon Apr 06 14:37:28.669698 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7784:tid 1048] [client 95.47.51.217:48374]   File "c:\\users\\adwy\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\conf\\__init__.py", line 66, in _setup\r
[Mon Apr 06 14:37:28.669698 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7784:tid 1048] [client 95.47.51.217:48374]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)\r
[Mon Apr 06 14:37:28.669698 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7784:tid 1048] [client 95.47.51.217:48374]   File "c:\\users\\adwy\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\conf\\__init__.py", line 157, in __init__\r
[Mon Apr 06 14:37:28.669698 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7784:tid 1048] [client 95.47.51.217:48374]     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)\r
[Mon Apr 06 14:37:28.669698 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7784:tid 1048] [client 95.47.51.217:48374]   File "c:\\users\\adwy\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib\\importlib\\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module\r
[Mon Apr 06 14:37:28.669698 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7784:tid 1048] [client 95.47.51.217:48374]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)\r
[Mon Apr 06 14:37:28.669698 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7784:tid 1048] [client 95.47.51.217:48374]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import\r
[Mon Apr 06 14:37:28.669698 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7784:tid 1048] [client 95.47.51.217:48374]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load\r
[Mon Apr 06 14:37:28.669698 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7784:tid 1048] [client 95.47.51.217:48374]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked\r
[Mon Apr 06 14:37:28.669698 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7784:tid 1048] [client 95.47.51.217:48374]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed\r
[Mon Apr 06 14:37:28.669698 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7784:tid 1048] [client 95.47.51.217:48374]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import\r
[Mon Apr 06 14:37:28.669698 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7784:tid 1048] [client 95.47.51.217:48374]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load\r
[Mon Apr 06 14:37:28.669698 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7784:tid 1048] [client 95.47.51.217:48374]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked\r
[Mon Apr 06 14:37:28.669698 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7784:tid 1048] [client 95.47.51.217:48374] ImportError: No module named 'weblog_app'\r
```

basically, I don't know if the problem is in the mod_wsgi version that I'm using or in the CONFIG that I used:

here I copy the CONFIG that I used for Apache

```
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/users/adwy/appdata/local/programs/python/python35/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp35-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIScriptAlias / "D:/Backup/Learning Python/Organized and important file/Learning files and sheets/Django_ Learning_ 1/weblog_app/weblog_app/wsgi.py"
WSGIPythonHome "c:/users/adwy/appdata/local/programs/python/python35"
WSGIPythonPath "D:/Backup/Learning Python/Organized and important file/Learning files and sheets/Django_ Learning_ 1/weblog_app/weblog_app"

Alias "/static/" "C:/Users/Adwy/Adwy/Django_ Learning_ 1/Lib/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static"
Alias "/templates/" "C:/Users/Adwy/Adwy/Django_ Learning_ 1/Lib/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates"


<Directory "C:/Users/Adwy/Adwy/Django_ Learning_ 1/Lib/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static">
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/Users/Adwy/Adwy/Django_ Learning_ 1/Lib/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates">
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "D:/Backup/Learning Python/Organized and important file/Learning files and sheets/Django_ Learning_ 1/weblog_app/weblog_app">
   <Files wsgi.py>
      Require all granted
   </Files>
</Directory>
```

Can anybody with some experience here help me,

thanks alot,

Comment: Just curious, are you using a new project, or did you try uploading an existing developed project, I got this error when I was missing dependencies.

Comment: I tried to follow a tutorial building a blog project to learn .. I didn't upload any project, I started to build everything from the beginning .. can you explain more?

Comment: Well one of the things that can cause this error is if your django project doesn't have the correct packages installed. If its listed in the settings.py, it needs to be installed and accessible in the server environment. For example if the using a plugin such as CrispyForms, you need to ensure its in your requirements and then ensure its installed in the server environment. Hope you can figure it out